# How to set the value of a select to match&tokenize jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bind a function to the select field when something is pasted into it (it looks like an input field after allowing multiple style and select2:matcher/tokenize) but in IE it always truncates any pasted text which contains a new line character.

```
<form method="POST" action="/run" class="ui-widget" onsubmit=" return confirmSubmit(this, 'run',true) ">
    Editor:
    <select name="editor" id="editor" multiple style="width: 200px">
        <option>ALL</option>
    </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

`bind('paste')` does not seem to work on an `<select>` object so I had to use `bind('change')`

```
var unitIds = ["Red","Yellow","Green"];

$.each(unitIds, function(i, f) {
        $('select[name="editor"]').append($('<option>').text(f));
    });

$('#pastefromclip').select2({
    matcher: function(term, text) {
                    return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) === 0;
                },
    tokenizer: function(input, selection, callback) {
                    if (input.indexOf(" ") < 0) return;
                    var parts = input.split(" ");
                for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                    var part = parts[i];
                    if(part.length > 0){
                        if (unitIds.indexOf(part) == -1) {
                            alert('Invalid fields: ' + part);
                        } else {
                            callback({
                                id: part,
                                text: part
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
});
$('#editor').bind('change', function (e) {
            var clipped = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
            clipped = clipped.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, " "); //replace newlines with spaces
            //$(this).val(clipped); // this doesn't seem to work
            var element = document.getElementById('editor');
            element.value = clipped; // doesn't seem to work either
            return false; //cancel the pasting event
        });
```

1. Copy and paste the following into the select field:
   Red
   Yellow
2. It pastes only 'Red' and shows the matched object. It does not recognise the change function until I select that matched object and it is being tokenized.
3. After it recognises that change, it runs through the clipboardData and sees both Red and Yellow but it cannot assign the select field with that data.

   ```
   <script src="https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/plugins/jquery.jqgrid.showhidecolumnmenu.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jqGrid/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jqGrid/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/toastr.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/adminConsole.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/select2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/moment.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jqGrid/ui.multiselect.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jqGrid/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
   ```

Comment: why you use `select` why not `input type='text'`? Red and yellow should be added to `select` or just replace first element(*ALL*)?

Comment: InternetExplorer only: http://jsfiddle.net/fxrzm3tL/48/

Comment: because I originally only needed a select box, then expanded the feature to being able to match & tokenize. It worked perfectly fine in CHrome. Now I want to avoid having to change all my select functions.

Comment: The code in your jsfiddle unfortunately doesn't seem to work for me. I added the javascript which populates the options as well as sets the matcher/tokenizer. the  jsfiddle doesnt seem to change the select box into an input field though.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fxrzm3tL/50/

Comment: tested on ie9 and it works well : http://jsfiddle.net/fxrzm3tL/48

It add an option with "Red Yellow" and don't truncate it. The last fiddle don't work cause there are no libraries loaded.

Comment: Thanks but what I need is for it to show the editor field not as a list, but as a free character input box (even though it is specified as `<select>`) for which if you start typing, it shows the suggested values. similar to here: http://jsfiddle.net/ct5172sk/ Now I know this example uses `<input>` but i want the same functionality with `<select>`. It works perfectly fine in Chrome but not in IE

Comment: I basically need this to work in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/ct5172sk/

Answer (score 0):

use TokenSeparators for multiple inputs

[See it Action](http://jsfiddle.net/XQ8Fw/)

```
    $(".js-example-tokenizer").select2({
  tags: true,
  tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
})
```

Please refer the section Automatic tokenization in [Select2 Tokenization](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Also when Copy paste the options (Red Green ) don't forget to append "," at last

Comment: opening your link and pasting the text "A B C" (with new line characters instead of space) it gets cut off at A in IE